# Choco Solver - Variables association

Tags: constraints, solver, constraint-programming, choco

I'm using [choco solver 4.0.5 (latest until now)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.choco-solver/choco-solver) and the few examples on the web besides not contemplating my need, use older version.

I'm absolutely a begginner on choco solver, and after very hard search on the web, I came here to ask help.


I have the following variables domain:

**Days of year:** 1 (represents 1-jan), 35 (represents 4-feb), 58, 56, 125, 142, 168, 225, 360, 364...
**People Ids:** 789111, 789555, 78496, 879...

I need create a constraint in order that people don't be associated on a consecutive days, but alternate them in a balanced way like:

```
1 = 789111
35 = 789555
58 = 789496
56 = 879
125 = 789111
142 = 789555
168 = 789496
225 = 879
360 = 789111
364 = 789496 (the 789555 is unavailable here)
```

How can I represent this on choco solver 4.0.5?

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribute events evenly over time is not an easy thing to model. A simple "proxy" is: forbid people to work on days that are close. E.g. at least two days in between. This can be modeled as:

```
worker w works at t => w cannot work at t+1 and t+2
```

If you would model this as `x[w,t]=1` iff w works at t then this becomes:

```
x[w,t]=1 => x[w,t+1]=0 and x[w,t+2]=0
```